# How do I specify a URL between containers inside an ASP.NET application, appsettings.json?

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

Please tell me how to correctly set the URL address in the variable  `"GRpcApiUri": "."` in `appsettings.json`, which will be available after creating `webui` container?

We have `opcua` and `webui` containers connected by a single local network via `docker-compose.yml` file:

[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBJNv.png)

After command `docker-compose up -d`, the `webui` container gives the result available via `http://localhost:8080` (static web page)

In file `appsettings.json` settings via the `GRpcApiUri` variable, the `opcua` container should send data to `http://localhost:8080` that it receives from the external `FakeOpcServer`.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  },
  "ReaderId": 1,
  "GRpcApiUri": "http://localhost:8080",
  ...
}
```

I understand correctly that both containers are inside the same control network, meaning they communicate through the names of the services, namely `http://webui:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080`.

And when I put in `appsettings.json` this value

```
"GRpcApiUri": "http://webui:8080"
```

and start the container I get:

> fail: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[6]
> Error starting gRPC call.
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ThrowGetVersionException(HttpRequestMessage request, Int32 desiredVersion)

Immediately I will say that I tried various options both *http://localhost:8080*, and *http:/127.0.0.1:8080* and *http://IPContainer:8080* and many different, played ports, but errors are always. *FakeOpcServer* is on another host and the connection check passes, and then **opcui** produces a communication error with **webui**.

Everything works if I run from VS studio, but through the docker can not bind 2 containers in appsettings.

[webui.dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvX7c.png)  [opcua.dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DZjO.png)

Comment: as per compose file, your webui is listening on 80 port inside container. within same docker network you have to use internal port not the external mapped one. so in your case, to access webui you should use `"GRpcApiUri": "http://webui:80"`.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the application stack in Swarm, containers communicate with each other by the name of the service, that is, the port does not need to be specified unless it has changed (80 or 443). In this case the address will be given:
on 80 port `http:/webui;`
on 443 port `https://webui;`

If the port on which the attachment works changed and is worth 8456 for example, then the path is `http/s://webui:8456`